# How can I easily deal with differences between BSD and GNU sed?

Tags: sed, gnu, bsd, portability

BSD and GNU sed have some small differences in what arguments they accept. I just learned that I have to use different command lines when using `-i`:

```
sed -i '' # BSD
sed -i    # GNU
```

I solved this with an IMO ugly hack involving storing the correct parameter in an environment variable.

Is there a nicer way to do that?

Comment: Yeah. [Don't use -i](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2013-09/msg00000.html). It's just an ugly hack anyway.

Comment: You think so? I use it all the time..

Comment: Yes. Of course it's called *in-place editing* but that's not at all what it is. Rather it's *replace*. It's riddled with problems where user/group permissions are concerned, fs quotas, timestamps, and what-have-you. Anyway, there is an answer to your question.